# show message in new windows

Tags: c#

now program show Messagebox and wait user decision.
How make, that program don't wait?
Show Messagebox, ant keep going.
(I do not need a user action. I just need to show text)

Or maybe a better option than to report the information to a new window?

I hope to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and easy way: use a `BackgroundWorker` to host your long running job and use the worker's events to pop up messages in the UI thread.

edit: might want to display the messages in the form of a message log.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    #region Constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add("Job started!");
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // send data from the background thread
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, i);
        }
    }
    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // communicate with UI thread
        listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("Received message: {0}", e.UserState));
    }
    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add("Job done!");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx), put some controls on it and show it to the user:

```
new PopupForm().Show();
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to use the "new PopupForm (). Show ();?
Does not understand.

Comment: You need to add a new windows form to your project naming it `PopupForm`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to show a notification window, then [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/Notifier.aspx) would be a help that I wrote sometime back; works like Outlook like notification window.

[image]